# Simpler/preferred way to iterate over two equal-length lists and append the max of each pair to a new list?

Tags: python, list, max

Given two lists of equal length, is there a simpler or preferred way to iterate over two lists of equal length and append the maximum of each pair of elements to a new list? These are the two methods I know of.

```
import itertools

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,1,6,3,8]
m1 = list()
m2 = list()

for x, y in zip(a, b):
    m1.append(max(x, y))

for x in itertools.imap(max, a, b):
    m2.append(x)
```

Both of these result in `[1, 2, 6, 4, 8]`, which is correct. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
map(max, a, b)
[max(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: That first line of code is definitely the simplest so far. Perfect for code golf too!

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,1,6,3,8]
m3 = [max(x,y) for (x,y) in zip(a,b)]
```

or even

```
m4 = map(max, zip(a,b))
```

Comment: That's the same as my first solution except using list comprehensions, right? (I'm not criticising it because of the similarity, though). Are list comprehensions preferred?

Comment: It is basically the same, yeah -- I suppose it's just a matter of preference.  I like it because it's "short" but that's just me.

Comment: List comprehensions are a better solution, as they read better in code. It's more clear what is happening, and easier to change.

Answer (score -1):

In Python3, `map()` no longer returns a list, so you should use the list comprehension or

```
list(map(max, a, b))
```

if you really need a list and not just an iterator

Comment: This should probably be a comment on Ignacio's answer.